# Plone:Folderish content type generated with Dexterity. How do I populate it's file, image and rich text fields?

Tags: content-type, plone, variable-assignment, dexterity

I have made some new content type using Dexterity. I now wish to create the content from a python script. All is well with the line below, and the item is generated in the target folder with the correct **id** and **date**. But how do you pass the file data to a **file** field, the **image** data to the image field and the **richt_text** data to the rich_text field?

```
target.invokeFactory(type_name="content_type_name", id=id, date=date, file=file, image=image, rich_text=rich_text)
```

The date I could figure out; Dexterity wants the Python datetime format:

```
datetime.datetime(2011,1,1)
```

Thank you very much for your help - I am sure I am missing something quite elementary here, but haven't found it - probably because I am looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 7):

For file use plone.namedfile.NamedFile and for image use plone.namedfile.NamedImage and for rich text use plone.app.textfield.value.RichTextValue

e.g.

```py
from plone.namedfile import NamedFile
from plone.namedfile import NamedImage
from plone.app.textfield.value import RichTextValue

file = NamedFile("<html></html>", "text/html", u"text.html")
logo = ... some binary data in a byte string ...
image = NamedImage(logo, filename="logo.gif")
rich_text = RichTextValue(u"<p>A paragraph</p>", 'text/html', 
        'text/x-html-safe', 'utf-8')
target.invokeFactory(type_name="content_type_name", id=id, date=date, file=file,
        image=image, rich_text=rich_text)
```

Comment: Horst, if this answers your question you could mark my answer as such using the stackoverflow UI